# Express get router not returning whole parameter

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I've got the following code:

```
app.get('/torrent/', function (req, res) {
  res.json(req.query.magnet);
});
```

So when I visit `http://server.com/torrent/?magnet=<insertmagneturlhere>` I would like the whole magnet URL to be in the response.

Here's an example of a whole magnet: `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:550321C3982A023C474A61C37E3082D9EA1C12CC&dn=some+file+name+here&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce`

However I'm only getting this: `"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:550321C3982A023C474A61C37E3082D9EA1C12CC"`

What about the & escapes the response and stops it there and how can I get the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange looking uri, but the & is the separator between query arguments, so you actually have more than one. Try reading the next one wth:

```
req.queryquery.dn
```

And the one after that as

```
req.query.tr
```

Comment: It's a magnet URL which is used in torrent's nowadays. This got me very close...however where ```some+file+name+here``` is in my original url got replaced with ```some file name here``` I need to put the + where the spaces are.

Comment: I suppose I could do this... ```res.json(req.query.magnet + "&dn=" + req.query.dn.split(' ').join('+') + "&tr=" + req.query.tr);``` is that the best way?

Comment: The you need to urlencode each of the patameters, if encoding hashes p handles spaces like that. But it doesn't. It encodes spaces as %20. You'll just need to replace the spaces with pluses. Or try to access the raw query string.